# Incomplete Thread Dump on Control+Break

Tags: java, thread-dump

Noticed weird thing when running simple Spring Boot application in IntelliJ IDEA CE 2018.3: Pressing "Dump Threads" button in Run view (or pressing Control+Break in the same view) leads to thread dump that is incomplete despite promising "Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.151-b12 mixed mode):". For example, there are no "http-nio-9090-exec-N" threads while attached Java Mission Control shows them.

When I run the same application in Git Bash or Windows cmd.exe it dumps all threads.

Answer (score 0):

Root cause is a bag in IntelliJ IDEA - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-203403.
May be that IDE action dump threads of the maven process itself, not the process running inside.